# jsPlumb touch event working on web browser but not on tablet browser

Tags: android, jquery, jsplumb

I have made match the columns template using jsplumb in which i have used drag and drop feature. all is working fine on web browsers. but when i run the same on tablet browser it is not working. I read the forums in which they have suggested to use touchpunch. i used that also. but when i tap the circle to match with the other column, it dont move. Please suggest where is the mistake.
the code snippet that i have used is:

main.js

```
function display()
{                
    var questiontxt = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("questionTxt")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    $("#topmain").html(questiontxt);

    fitemid= x[0].getElementsByTagName("item").length;
    ftargetid= x[0].getElementsByTagName("target").length;
    $("#listitem").append('<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8" style="width: 95%; " id="list"></table>');
    connections = [];

    jsPlumb.importDefaults({
        ConnectionsDetachable:true,
        ReattachConnections:true
    });

    updateConnections = function(conn, remove) {
        connections.push(conn);
        hideConnectionInfo(connections[0].sourceId);
    };

    window.jsPlumbDemo = {
        init : function() {
            var exampleDropOptions = {
                tolerance:"touch",
                hoverClass:"dropHover",
                activeClass:"dragActive"
            };

            var color2 = "#FFF";
            var color3 = "#09F";
            var exampleEndpoint2 = {
                tolerance:"touch",
                hoverClass:"dropHover",
                activeClass:"dragActive",
                endpoint:["Dot", { radius:15 }],
                paintStyle:{ fillStyle:color3 },
                isSource:true,
                scope:"green dot",
                connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:color3, lineWidth:2 },
                maxConnections:1,
                connector: "Straight",
                isTarget:false
            };

            var exampleEndpoint3 = {
                endpoint:["Dot", { radius:15}],
                paintStyle:{ fillStyle:color3 },
                isSource:false,
                scope:"green dot",
                connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:color3, lineWidth:2 },
                maxConnections:1,
                connector: "Straight",
                isTarget:true,
                beforeDrop:function(params) { 
                    var v=(params.sourceId).substring(6,(params.sourceId).length);
                    var w=(params.targetId).substring(12,(params.targetId).length);

                    if(v == w){
                        document.getElementById('ans'+w).innerHTML+="<img src='img/correct.png'>";
                        count++;
                        c = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item").length;

                        if(count == c){
                            feedback();
                            alert(window.parent)
                            window.parent.updateResult(100)
                        }
                        return confirm(); 
                        dropOptions : exampleDropOptions    

                    }
                }
            };

            jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(info, originalEvent) {
                updateConnections(info.connection);
            });

            jsPlumb.bind("connectionDetached", function(info, originalEvent) {
                updateConnections(info.connection, true);
            });

            function Shuffle(o) {
                for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
                    return o;
                };

            var testArray = new Array();
            var testArray1 = new Array();

            for(i=0 ; i< fitemid ;i++){
                testArray.push(i);
            }
            Shuffle(testArray);

            for(i=0 ; i< fitemid ;i++){
                testArray1.push(i);
            }
            Shuffle(testArray1);

            for(i=0 ; i< fitemid ;i++)
            {
                fitem[i] = x[0].getElementsByTagName("item")[testArray1[i]].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                ftarget[i] = x[0].getElementsByTagName("target")[testArray[i]].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

                j = x[0].getElementsByTagName("item")[testArray1[i]].getAttribute("target");
                l = x[0].getElementsByTagName("target")[testArray[i]].getAttribute("id");

                $("#list").append("<tr style='width:100%;'><td id=\"circle"+j+"\" class='circle ,\"circle"+j+"\' style='width:65%; vertical-align: top; border:1px #999 solid; float:left; border-radius:4px;'>"+fitem[i]+"</td> <td id=\"circletarget"+l+"\" class='circletarget,\"circle"+j+"\' style='vertical-align: top; width:59%; border:1px #999 solid; border-radius:4px;'>"+ftarget[i]+"</td><td class='circletarget,\"circle"+j+"\' style='vertical-align: top; width:5%;'><div id=\"ans"+l+"\" class='ans'></td></tr>");

                var e1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("circle"+j, { anchor:[1, 0.5, 1, 1 ] }, exampleEndpoint2);
                var e2 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("circletarget"+l, { anchor:[ 0, 0.5, 1, 1 ] }, exampleEndpoint3);

                jsPlumb.draggable($("#circle"+j,"#circletarget"+l));
            }   
        }       
    };  
    jsPlumbDemo.init(); 
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
                 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.8.1-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.23-min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/lib/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js" ></script>

        <script src="js/lib/jsBezier-0.5.js"></script>      
        <!-- jsplumb util -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-util-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>
        <!-- base DOM adapter -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-dom-adapter-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>
        <!-- jsplumb drag-->
        <!--<script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-drag-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>-->
        <!-- main jsplumb engine -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>
        <!-- connectors, endpoint and overlays  -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-defaults-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>
        <!-- SVG renderer -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-renderers-svg-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>
        <!-- canvas renderer -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-renderers-canvas-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>
        <!-- vml renderer -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jsPlumb-renderers-vml-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>

        <!-- jquery jsPlumb adapter -->
        <script src="js/1.4.0/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.0-RC1.js"></script>

</head>

    <body>

 <div id="content" class="content">         

                <div id="topmain"></div>
                <div id="listitem"></div>
            </div>

 </body>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jsPlumb creates a SVG that can stay over an element connected, preventing the click to trigger the event on element under SVG.

You can test it by attach an click event on all SVG's created by jsPlumb and check your click triggering that.

The solution has worked to me was to change the z-index of the elements under the SVG to a z-index greater than the z-index that was set in instance of jsPlumb.

BTW, you can control the z-index of the connectors with:

jsPlumb.importDefaults({ ConnectorZIndex: number }); //number is the z-index